# mplayer crash -> login screen

Tags: debian, crash, mplayer, radeon

I have a file that pretty reproducibly makes `mplayer` crash. When it occurs, the whole session in crashed and I get back to the login page.

From my tests,

- `smplayer`: crash is systematic
- `mplayer`: crash is not systematic but occurs regularly (even 1 time out of 10 can arguably be qualified reproducible)

In any case, before the crash or if it doesn't crash, the image is sort of skewed.

I'm using Debian Jessie:

```
MPlayer2 2.0-728-g2c378c7-4+b1
SMPlayer v. 14.9.0
lightdm 1.10.3-3
```

Graphic card ATI/AMD R7 240:

```
VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland PRO [Radeon R7 240]
```

using `radeon` free driver.

It happens with both 10.3 and 13.0 (backported) versions of `mesa` stuff. And with both Linux 3.16 and 4.9.

File is

```
H264-MPEG4 AVC (part10)(avc1)
```

`vlc` reads it fine.

Nothing thrilling in the logs:

.xsession-errors:

```
xterm: fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) or KillClient on X server ":0.0"^M
python3: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.

(smart-notifier:9254): Gdk-WARNING **: smart-notifier: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.


(nm-applet:9280): Gdk-WARNING **: nm-applet: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.

mate-volume-control-applet: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.
Avertissement du gestionnaire de fenêtres : Erreur fatale d'E/S 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) sur le visuel « :0 ».
polkit-mate-authentication-agent-1: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.
mate-panel: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.
mate-screensaver: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.
caja: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.
mate-settings-daemon: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.
x-session-manager: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.
[1487513131,000,xklavier.c:xkl_engine_start_listen/]    The backend does not require manual layout management - but it is provided by the application
mate-power-manager: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.
```

/var/log/syslog:

```
Feb 19 15:05:23 bouzin org.mate.panel.applet.ClockAppletFactory[8883]: clock-applet: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.
Feb 19 15:05:23 bouzin org.a11y.atspi.Registry[8994]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
Feb 19 15:05:23 bouzin org.a11y.atspi.Registry[8994]: after 123 requests (123 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Feb 19 15:05:23 bouzin org.mate.panel.applet.NotificationAreaAppletFactory[8883]: notification-area-applet: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.
Feb 19 15:05:23 bouzin org.mate.panel.applet.WnckletFactory[8883]: wnck-applet: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.
Feb 19 15:05:23 bouzin org.a11y.atspi.Registry[8841]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
Feb 19 15:05:23 bouzin org.a11y.atspi.Registry[8841]: after 131 requests (131 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Feb 19 15:05:23 bouzin org.a11y.Bus[8835]: g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
Feb 19 15:05:23 bouzin org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[8883]: A connection to the bus can't be made
Feb 19 15:05:23 bouzin org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[8883]: g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
Feb 19 15:05:23 bouzin ca.desrt.dconf[8883]: g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
Feb 19 15:05:23 bouzin org.gtk.Private.UDisks2VolumeMonitor[8883]: g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Erreur lors de la réception du message : Connexion ré-initialisée par le correspondant (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
Feb 19 15:05:23 bouzin org.gtk.Private.AfcVolumeMonitor[8883]: g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Erreur lors de la réception du message : Connexion ré-initialisée par le correspondant (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
Feb 19 15:05:23 bouzin org.gtk.Private.MTPVolumeMonitor[8883]: g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Erreur lors de la réception du message : Connexion ré-initialisée par le correspondant (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
Feb 19 15:05:23 bouzin org.gtk.Private.GoaVolumeMonitor[8883]: g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Erreur lors de la réception du message : Connexion ré-initialisée par le correspondant (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
Feb 19 15:05:23 bouzin org.gtk.Private.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor[8883]: g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Erreur lors de la réception du message : Connexion ré-initialisée par le correspondant (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
Feb 19 15:05:23 bouzin org.a11y.Bus[8883]: g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
Feb 19 15:05:23 bouzin org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[8883]: g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
Feb 19 15:05:24 bouzin lightdm[949]: ** (process:9153): WARNING **: Error getting user list from org.freedesktop.Accounts: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Accounts was not provided by any .service files
Feb 19 15:05:24 bouzin systemd[1]: Starting Session c6 of user lightdm.
Feb 19 15:05:24 bouzin systemd[1]: Started Session c6 of user lightdm.
Feb 19 15:05:24 bouzin org.a11y.Bus[9162]: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Feb 19 15:05:24 bouzin org.a11y.Bus[9162]: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Feb 19 15:05:24 bouzin org.a11y.atspi.Registry[9168]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Feb 19 15:05:29 bouzin lightdm[949]: ** (process:9178): WARNING **: Error getting user list from org.freedesktop.Accounts: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Accounts was not provided by any .service files
Feb 19 15:05:29 bouzin systemd[1]: Starting Session 9 of user jerome.
Feb 19 15:05:29 bouzin systemd[1]: Started Session 9 of user jerome.
```

As long as it is restricted to a specific series of files, I can live with it, but I'd like to make myself useful and report this where it helps. Except I don't know where to point my finger. `mplayer`? `radeon`?

Comment: I think you should open a Debian bug report against *mplayer*. Use the *reportbug* tool. The maintainer will reassign the bug if needed.

Comment: Right. Done: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=855629